Dart define correct prevariable to use into for statement
Dart correct define prevariable to use into for statement
In the Dart programming language, I previously wrote this loop:
for (final item in tempAddress) {
  addresses.add(AddressCollection()
    ..label = item.label
    ..lat = item.lat
    ..long = item.long
  );
}

Now, I’m unable to define item.label and the others to use them from a list or a map. For example, I wrote this code:
final tempAddress = [
  {
    'label': 'new label'
  }
];

But it throws an error saying label is not defined as a map. I then defined it like this:
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> tempAddress = [
  {
    'label': 'new label'
  }
];

But I still get the same error.
@collection
class AddressCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  @Backlink(to: 'locations')
  final profile = IsarLink<ProfileCollection>();

  @Backlink(to: 'orderLocation')
  final order = IsarLink<OrdersCollection>();

  late double lat;
  late double long;
  late String address;
  late String deliveryOption;
  String? businessName = '';
  String? streetAddress = '';
  late int postCode;
  late String city;
  int? unitNumber = 0;
  String? label = '';
  bool? isDefault = false;
}

What is the correct way to define this variable?

Huh?  The last one works for me.

@RandalSchwartz could you see this screen shot please: https://imgur.com/a/BYlqLqu

@pskink POST UPDATED, i get this error: The getter 'label' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.  screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/BYlqLqu

@pskink i'm trying to fill AddressCollection array with the sample data in for statement

so you need something like this: final tempAddress = [ AddressCollection(...), AddressCollection(...) ]; - tempAddress has to be a List<AddressCollection> and not List<Map>

Dart is not JavaScript.  Objects are not dictionaries/maps.  If you want to do a lookup on a Map, you need to use Map.operator[].  If you want to access a member of an object, the class for that object must declare a member with that name.

I'm not so advance in Flutter and Dart but learner.
The problem is that the item in the loop is a Map<String,dynamic>, so you need to access the values using the correct key and type casting.
for ex:
for (final item in tempAddress) {
  addresses.add(AddressCollection()
    ..label = item['label'] as String
    ..lat = item['lat'] as double
    ..long = item['long'] as double
  );
}

Hope this helps.
